# Homogenous coordinate ring of the product of projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $k$ is a field (possibly not algebraic closed). I'm convinced that $\mathrm{Proj}~k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x_0x_3-x_1x_2)$ is $\mathbb{P}_k^1\times\mathbb{P}_k^1$ via the Segre embedding.

However, is it possible to directly show that $\mathrm{Proj}~k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x_0x_3-x_1x_2)=\mathbb{P}_k^1\times\mathbb{P}_k^1$ using the universal property of fibre product? (I struggled a lot to find the projection morphism.) Or is it only true for algebraic closed field?

Comment: This is proved in Thm 3.3 in Hartshorne CHII: You may cover $S:=\mathbb{P}^1\times_k \mathbb{P}^1$ by open affine sets $U_{ij}:=D(x_i)\times D(x_j) \cong Spec(k[u,v] \cong Spec(k[u]\otimes_k k[v])$ and reduce to the affine $Spec(k[u]\otimes_k k[v])$. Then you "glue". The  open covering $U_{ij}$ may be constructed directly for $Proj(k[x_0,..,x_3]/(x_0x_3-x_1x_2)$

Comment: When using the universal property of the fiber product you must define the two projection maps $p,q: S:=Proj(k[x_i]/(x_0x_3-x_1x_2)) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, and to do this you must identify $S$ as isomorphic to the product $S \cong \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: If you are given an abstractly embedded scheme $S \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ and ask: "Can I use the universal property of the "fiber product" to prove things about $S$" you must first identify $S$ as a product $S \cong X \times_k Y$.

Comment: ..and in the above situation this is equivalent to writing down the isomorphism $S \cong \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.